# Search format for listing all questions with a specific tag?

Tags: support, search

For example, I'd like to see every question that has been tagged with [baking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baking). Searching for `[baking]` will just return the description of the tag.

I've tried `[baking] *` and even `[baking]` followed by a common word such as `a` or `the`, but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

`[baking]` is the correct syntax.

Yes, it returns the tag wiki (what you call "the description"). Below it you will see the questions for this tag, in a sorting order defined above the tag wiki (you can switch between the order criteria listed by just clicking one of them). If you select a tag with lots of questions, like [baking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baking), you will have a really long list to page through, of course.

[image: screenshot search]

Comment: I think I must have a browser quirk (Chrome), because I don't get a list of questions and neither `Info` or `Newest` were highlighted. I tried it on IE and the behavior was as you described above. I went back to Chrome, clicked on `Newest` (I didn't try that before because the tooltip for newest says it gives the most recent questions, not all questions), the list came and `Newest` is now is automatically selected when I search for a tag.  `Newest` appears to return all questions so that is fine. The strange thing before, if I searched for `[baking] oven`, I did get a list of questions.

Comment: Must be more than just the browser involved, I get the normal results with Chrome (18.0.1025.162)

Comment: So do I now that I've selected a sort order for the first time.